# XMLHttpRequest on Phonegap - unauthorized 401 Error, but correct login data?

Tags: cordova, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-401

I'm just trying to get a XMLHttpRequest running in Phonegap, but it doesn't work. An alert told me, that I'm getting back an 401 status. As I already found out, this error means, that I'm not authorized to get the information. In a browser on my desktop a popup would show up, where I can enter username and password. After that it works well with the code below.

On Android this popup won't show up, but that's not the problem. I tried to test the request with the username and password given in the request like this:

```js
xmlhttp.open('get', 'https://my-url', true, "username", "password");
```

Unfortunately this is not working. So I tried the next possibility:

```js
xmlhttp.open('get', 'https://username:password@my-url', true);
```

But this is not working, too. I'm still getting an 401. Running the same code in Browser gives me the request without Auth-PopUp (so it's working!).

Now I am really confused. The certificate used at my request-url is an officially trusted one (not self signed). My config.xml says

```html
<access origin="*" />
```

so this also can't be the mistake... :(

Here's my code, I hope anyone of you could help me, thanks in advance!

```java
var xmlhttp = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();

function doReq() {

    xmlhttp.open('get', 'https://my-url', true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = showData;
    xmlhttp.send(null);

}

function showData() {

    var text = "<table><thead><tr><th>Category1</th><th>Category2</th><th>Category3</th><th>Category4</th></tr></thead>";

    document.getElementById("ausgabe").style.visibility = "visible";

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.status == 0) {

            jsonobj = eval( "(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")");

            for (i = 0; i < jsonobj.$resources.length; i++) {

            text += "<tr><td>" + jsonobj.$resources[i].Category1 + "</td><td>" + jsonobj.$resources[i].Category2 + "</td><td>" + jsonobj.$resources[i].Category3 + "</td><td>" + jsonobj.$resources[i].Category4 + "</td></tr>"

            }

            document.getElementById("ausgabe").innerHTML = text;

        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: One additional note: My request-URL is a dynamic one, which gives back data in json-format. It's working well on my browser and when I copy/paste the data into a txt-file and request it locally it's still working fine. So this should not be the problem?

EDIT2: Sometimes you are searching for hours and 5 minutes after writing a long post you finally get the answer.

I just set async to 'false" and now it is working... but don't ask me why... perhaps there is anyone who could explain it? :)

Comment: Did you ever find out a reason for this?

Comment: If you are searching for a solution of the problem, I already updated my post. It was caused by setting async to true. But if you want a reason for this, I have to say sorry... I don't know why it works... ;)

Comment: The solution works, I just wanted to know if there is a reason behind why it does. Thanks anyways.